# How to get a specific value out of the FormData object

Tags: html, forms, form-data

So I have this code here

```
var form = document.getElementById("myform");
var formData = new FormData(form);
```

Form only contains two textfields, with the names "title" and "text". Before I submit the form I want to get the value of title. I tried

```
console.log(formData.title); //undefined
console.log(formData[0]); //undefined
console.log(formData.get(title)); //title is not defined
console.log(formData.get('title')); // formData.get is not a function

var j = JSON.parse(formData);   
console.log(" formData  > " + j);// Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

var j = JSON.stringify(formData);   
console.log(" formData  > " + j.title); // undefined
```

How on God's green Earth can I get a specific value, based on the name of the input field ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like you can do this in a cross-browser friendly way. The closest you'll find it [`FormData.getAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/getAll) which isn't support in IE, Edge or Safari at present.

I'd recommend leaving conversion to `FormData` as late as possible in your code (i.e. where you send the request). Libraries like [form-serialize](https://github.com/defunctzombie/form-serialize) can help get you by if you need to use/mangle the form's value before submitting (alternatively just use the DOM directly).